# Where is the code repository for Microsoft.Extensions.Primitive 1.0.0-rc1-final?

Tags: .net

https://github.com/aspnet/Common only has the code up to 1.0.0-beta8.

Filler text to bypass StackOverflow arbitrary limit of question length.

Comment: @LexLi thank you for the canned response. If that search feature works, there's no need for this question. The closest thing I've got is the aspnet/Common repository and that is tagged only up to beta8. Google and Bing search with site operator also doesn't return much. I usually reserve this type of answer if I can prove that search *is* working, which isn't in this case.

Comment: @LexLi Yes, but not 1.0.0-rc1-final as asked (there was beta 8 and just now MS tagged rc2). Your comments are already encapsulated in the first line of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft recently tagged the repository with [1.0.0-rc2 version](https://github.com/aspnet/Common/releases/tag/1.0.0-rc2), this led me to believe that they just forgot to tag the commit for 1.0.0-rc1. The last commit prior to the rc1 release date (Nov 18 2015) was [cd982fd](https://github.com/aspnet/Common/commit/cd982fd443446d7b09a4c64980d9e9e1d3ab4e92).